# Posting a list of objects trough json to actionMethod in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, post

Seems there have been some talk about this issue before, but i will post this anyway..

```
Public Function test(ByVal val As List(Of TestObj)) As ActionResult
    For Each o In val

    Next
End Function
Class TestObj
    Property id As Integer
    Property name As String
End Class
```

When trying to call this function trough jQuery's post method the mvc framework is not able to convert my json into the val paremeter.
If i do a dump of my request it looks like this..

```
?Request.Form("val")
"[{"id":1,"name":"dsfdf"},{"id":2,"name":"dsfdf"},{"id":3,"name":"dsfdf"}]"
```

and the value of val is a list, but the json string is noth converted into the objects, so the count of the list is 0.

I have seen some solutions for this, implementing and using attributes, but ...
I have done this several times in the context of .asmx webservices and it works out of the box, so I hoped this would work like a charm in mvc as well..  :)
Is there something that I have missed or is the attribute approch the only way to do it?